# Parser (ICS/PHP) parses only first line

Tags: php, parsing, icalendar

I've got an ics-parser:

```
 <?php
class ics {
    /* Function is to get all the contents from ics and explode all the data according to the events and its sections */
    function getIcsEventsAsArray($file) {
        $icalString = file_get_contents ( $file );
        $icsDates = array ();
        /* Explode the ICs Data to get data as array according to string ‘BEGIN:’ */
        $icsData = explode ( "BEGIN:", $icalString );
        /* Iterating the icsData value to make all the start end dates as sub array */
        foreach ( $icsData as $key => $value ) {
            $icsDatesMeta [$key] = explode ( "\n", $value );
        }
        /* Iterating the Ics Meta Value */
        foreach ( $icsDatesMeta as $key => $value ) {
            foreach ( $value as $subKey => $subValue ) {
                /* to get ics events in proper order */
                $icsDates = $this->getICSDates ( $key, $subKey, $subValue, $icsDates );
            }
        }
        return $icsDates;
    }

    /* function is to avoid the elements which is not having the proper start, end  and summary information */
    function getICSDates($key, $subKey, $subValue, $icsDates) {
        if ($key != 0 && $subKey == 0) {
            $icsDates [$key] ["BEGIN"] = $subValue;
        } else {
            $subValueArr = explode ( ":", $subValue, 2 );
            if (isset ( $subValueArr [1] )) {
                $icsDates [$key] [$subValueArr [0]] = $subValueArr [1];
            }
        }
        return $icsDates;
    }
}


$obj = new ics();
$icsEvents = $obj->getIcsEventsAsArray( 'calender.ics' );

echo "<h1>2017</h1>";

if($icsEvents)
{
    $timeZone = date_default_timezone_get() ;
    unset($icsEvents[1]);
    foreach ($icsEvents as $key => $icsEvent)
    {
        $start = isset( $icsEvent ['DTSTART;VALUE=DATE'] ) ? $icsEvent ['DTSTART;VALUE=DATE'] : $icsEvent ['DTSTART'];
        $startDt = new DateTime ( $start );
        $startDt->setTimeZone ( new DateTimezone ( $timeZone ) );
        $startDate = $startDt->format ( 'm/d/Y h:i' );

        $eventMonth = $startDt->format ( 'M Y' );
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo $eventMonth; ?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo $icsEvent['SUMMARY']; ?></h3>
        <?php echo $startDate; ?>, <?php echo $icsEvent['DESCRIPTION']; ?>
        <?php
    }
}



?>
```

This parser takes an ics-file and puts the events from the ics-file to a html-page.

My ics-file looks like this:

```html
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//John Papaioannou/NONSGML Bennu 0.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:249@moo.banma.fileserver.com/moo
SUMMARY:Greet
DESCRIPTION:
CLASS:PUBLIC
LAST-MODIFIED:20170906T131259Z
DTSTAMP:20170926T093038Z
DTSTART:20170908T100000Z
DTEND:20170908T130000Z
CATEGORIES:Allgemeine Termine
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:420@moo.banma.fileserver.com/moo
SUMMARY:Make PC run again
DESCRIPTION:
CLASS:PUBLIC
LAST-MODIFIED:20170906T131300Z
DTSTAMP:20170926T093038Z
DTSTART:20170908T130000Z
DTEND:20170908T140000Z
```

Sometimes the description/summary has more than one line:

```
SUMMARY:Make PC run again
and show it to big boss
```

How do I have to change my parser-code that it displays all the summary-text and description text even if it's more than one line / even if it has a linebreak inside?

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to have to come up with some other definition for an individual item. You are currently splitting using the newline character: `$icsDatesMeta [$key] = explode ( "\n", $value );` To be honest though, I'm not sure you're going to be able to come up with something better if you don't have any restrictions on what characters can be entered into the fields.

Comment: You need to unfold the long lines first, as described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.1

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't know how to unfold the long lines. 

Isn't there a way to unfold the long lines via PHP-code?